# Access 2010 Superscript, Subscript, and Math Notations

Tags: microsoft-access, text-formatting, symbols

I am creating an Access 2010 database to read rich text files full of math questions. I have the necessary fields in rich text, but rich text does not seem to support superscript, subscript, and certain math notations. Is there a way for Access to import rich text files and correctly capture the relevant superscript formatting and symbols?